# Converting JSON format date to angular date filter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have a JSON date format data that I need to convert it to angular date and display.

The JSON date format is

```
  var close_date="\/Date(1151470800000-0500)\/"
```

In my html code I am calling function on load as follow..

```
//i have other fields in form that i am not showing for sake of simplicity. 
<form ng-repeat p in list>
       <div>
          <span ng-model="p.close_date" ng-init="fn(p.close_date)"> {{p.close_date}}</span>
       </div> 
</form>
```

My ctroller is..

```
formsApp.controller('pCtrl', function ($scope, pRepository, $location) {
    $scope.lisr = pRepository.query();

    $scope.fn = function (close_date) {
        return eval("new " + close_date.replace(/\\|\//g, ''))
    }
});
```

When I run the code it should be displaying Jun 27, 2006 11:59:59 PM
But it doesnt and still shows the jason format date. Can you please let me know how to fix it. I suspect the ng-init is not being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngInit` will run your expression, but you don't assign the value anywhere. Also you don't need to use `ng-model` unless it's a "two way" binding, just use templating instead.

A couple of options to achieve what you want.

**Don't use ngInit and just interploate the function call**

```
<form ng-repeat p in list>
       <div>
          <span>{{fn(p.close_date)}}</span>
       </div> 
</form>
```

**Assign a value in ngInit**

```
<form ng-repeat p in list>
       <div>
          <span ng-init="myDate = fn(p.close_date)">{{myDate}}</span>
       </div> 
</form>
```